# Eclipse Error installing NatTable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nattable

I'm trying to install NatTable in Eclipse. All the parts installed successfully except this one: NatTable Eclipse 4 Extension Feature.

This is the error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: NatTable Eclipse 4 Extension Feature 1.0.0.201606011907 (org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201606011907)
  Missing requirement: NatTable extension for Eclipse 4 1.0.0.201606011907 (org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4 1.0.0.201606011907) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core 0.11.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: NatTable Eclipse 4 Extension Feature 1.0.0.201606011907 (org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201606011907)
    To: org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4 [1.0.0.201606011907]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you trying to install on?

Comment: Luna. Do I need NatTable 1.3?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirement for the E4 extension is Eclipse Neon, as some issues needed to be fixed in order to make it work.

This is explained in the New & Noteworthy page http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_140.php

And also in the Getting Started Tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html

Comment: Thank you. I have Eclipse Luna. Does that mean I need to use NatTable release 1.3?

Comment: No, it means you can not use the E4 extension. So you can't use CSS styling and the E4 selection listener. Which is actually easy to implement yourself. All other bundles have less dependencies and work fine even with Eclipse versions before Luna. Please check the provided links  for detailed information.

Comment: The Getting Started tutorial requires Neon and the E4 extension to complete the exercises. Is there any alternative tutorial that I can use with Luna?

Comment: No there is no alternative tutorial and you can complete the tutorial without the E4 extension. It is not required for that.